# Javascript sort array of variables and return a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, sorting, return

so I use JavaScript and I have an array of variables.

```
var a=5,b=10,c=3,d=11,e=0; //5 Variables with randomly chosen values
var myArray=[a,b,c,d,e]; 
myArray.sort(); //sort them, so the lowest value or variable is on first place
alert("This Variable has the lowest value: " + myArray[0]); 
//tell me the variable with the lowest value
```

So basically, i will get this text: "This Variable has the lowest value: 0"

But what i want is: "This Variable has the lowest value: e"

How can i return the variable, instead of the value of the variable?

Best Regards
qweret

Comment: check this thread, it contains the ansewrs [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make an **array of objects**:

```
var array = [{key: 'a', value: 5}, {key: 'b', value: 10}, {key: 'c', value: 3}, {key: 'd', value: 10}, {key: 'e', value: 0}];
```

Then you apply a `sort` function:

```
array.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
   return obj1.value - obj2.value;
});
```

Show the alert:

```
alert("This Variable has the lowest value: " + array[0].key);
```

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/asgoth/mKGbg/).

Comment: This is awesome! Worked like butter, thats exactly what i wanted. Didn't knew you could make such objects, but now that i know it, it sounds very logical! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

as shown [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml) use a sort function as an argument to the sort method call.

for example:

```
myArray.sort(myArraySortFunction);

function myArraySortFunction(a, b) {

}
```

you should take a look at javascript associative arrays as described [here](http://www.laurencegellert.com/2012/01/associative-arrays-in-javascript/)